# CodeIgniter - routing and pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my first attempt at pagination in CI, and I am facing a little problem, propably caused by routing.

My rules are as follow:

```
$route['User/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'User/index/$1';
$route['user/(:num)/(:any)'] = 'User/index/$1';
```

Those are translated to something like `http://site.com/index.php/user/1/tomek`.

Now my pagination controller:

```
$config['base_url'] = site_url('user').'/'.$user.'/'.$data['user'][0]['nick'].'/';
$config['total_rows'] = $this->rating_model->countOwned($user);
$config['per_page'] = 2;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = true;
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
...
$data['owns'] = $this->rating_model->getOwned($data['user'][0]['id'],$config['total_rows'],$config['per_page']);
```

In my model, I used simple `limit`:

```
public function getOwned($user,$limit,$start) {
    $this->db->limit($limit,$start);
    ...
```

Links and all works fine, but they doesn't work. I am getting an url like `http://site.com/index.php/user/1/tomek/2`, but items are still intact. Where is my mistake?

edit> complete controller code:

```
public function index($user = null) {
        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('user_data');
        $this->db->cache_off();

        if($session_data) :

            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
            $this->load->library('pagination');
            $this->load->model('user_model');
            $this->load->model('rating_model');
            $this->load->model('games_model');

            if($user) {
                $user = $user;
            } else {
                $user = $session_data['id'];
            }

            //vars
                $data['user'] = $this->user_model->getUser($user);
                $data['title'] = $data['user'][0]['nick'].' · Profil użytkownika';
                $data['age'] = $this->user_model->getAge($data['user'][0]['birth']);
                $data['sex'] = $this->user_model->getSex($data['user'][0]['sex']);

                $config['base_url'] = site_url('user').'/'.$user.'/'.$data['user'][0]['nick'].'/';
                $config['total_rows'] = $this->rating_model->countOwned($user);
                $config['per_page'] = 4;
                $config['enable_query_strings'] = true;
                $this->pagination->initialize($config);

                $data['pages'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

                $data['rates'] = $this->rating_model->countRates($user);
                $data['rates2'] = $this->rating_model->countGrades($user);

                $data['developers'] = $this->games_model->getDevelopers();
                $data['genres'] = $this->games_model->getGenres();
                $data['platforms'] = $this->games_model->getPlatforms();

                $data['nowPlaying'] = $this->rating_model->getNowPlaying($data['user'][0]['id']);

                $data['owns'] = $this->rating_model->getOwned($data['user'][0]['id'],$config['total_rows'],$config['per_page']);

                //load
                $this->template->load('template','theme/yourAccount/main', $data);

        else :

                $this->load->view('unlogged');

        endif;
    }
```

Comment: where is the `uri->segment` ?

Comment: the fourth uri segment should be passed to the `$start` in your model. Is it happening? If yes,how are you doing that?

Comment: I dont' pass that forth segment. How can I do this? I am following CI's tutorial (http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html).

Answer (score 0):

the following url "http://site.com/index.php/user/1/tomek/2" needs:
$route['User/(:num)/(:any)/(:num)'] = 'User/index/$1/$2/$3';

You can probably leave index out of the route. Because this is the standard function it calls.

Comment: I added this route, but it didn't helped.

Comment: does it reach your index function? Did you place an die() and test?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually in `uri_segment`. I had to point out, which part of url is the page number. Like this: `$config['uri_segment'] = 5;` And I load my page with:

```
$data['owns'] = $this->rating_model->getOwned($data['user'][0]['id'],4,$this->uri->segment(5));
```

Works great. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help. 2 important factors in pagination are the uri segment and the limit offset for the query. It may also help you if you will try to complete the $config's(not necessary those used for formatting) like the $cofig['uri_segment'].

Try to check this link and check the structure and algorithm, it might help.
    [Codeigniter, setting up pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572085/codeigniter-setting-up-pagination/13576738#13576738)